installing arrow for R failed on macos
I have 2022 MacBook Pro, M1 chip, 16GB RAM, Sonoma 14.5 OS, latest RStudio version to use R for data science. I successfully loaded the package 'pkg-config' (version 0.29.2). I want to access large datasets efficienty, which Apache's 'arrow' package is said to facilitate. But I can’t get arrow to load successfully.
The log of my first attempt indicated pkg-config failed to install, so I located the latest version 0.29.2 version and installed it. To do this I had to install Homebrew via Terminal. The C++ libraries were apparently incompatible. I also tried installing ‘libarrow' but the log said that libarrow is not compatible with my version of R. For my latest attempt I ran this in R:
Sys.setenv(LIBARROW_MINIMAL = FALSE) 
install.packages("arrow", type = "source") 


But the install still does complete, with the error message: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arrow’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-arrow/00new/arrow/libs/arrow.so': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-arrow/00new/arrow/libs/arrow.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ZN3re212re2_internal5ParseINSt3__117basic_string_viewIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEEEEEEbPKcmPT'
To see the whole install log I posted it here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WzVRBCEKAAA6g-1BdM1fWPNt2B7gSukXp0SRwLiBByE/edit?usp=drive_link
